# Add to cart Not Working Homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I want to show **feature product** on my **home page** but when I click on add to cart it take me to cart page and show empty cart but when I add product form category page or on detail page its working fine this is my cms block code

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured"  category_id="6" product_count="24" hide_button="0"   is_responsive="1"  breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 1], [480, 2], [768, 3], [960, 4], [1280, 5]" move="0" loop="1"  block_name="Featured Products" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Have you check if you have some JS errors ?

Comment: when i disable cache it work

Comment: contact ultimo for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problem in your form key, which contains the New Products with a "Add To Cart" Link which contains an old incorrect form key.

Try this:

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured"  category_id="6" product_count="24" hide_button="0"   is_responsive="1"  breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 1], [480, 2], [768, 3], [960, 4], [1280, 5]" move="0" loop="1"  block_name="Featured Products" cache_lifetime="1" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml"}}
```

Comment: is this cache issue and what is the mean by adding this code

Comment: It means that we set `cache_lifetime` on your new products block to the minimum allowed `1 second`

Comment: @Prince Same i am faced the issue, my error https://imgur.com/ZCxaxqq and https://imgur.com/j9syQgU could you pls help me to solve the issue?